# FCM Sending background notification to iOS, but iOS not receiving it

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I've been trying to implement a background notification to send to iOS using FCM and Firebase Console.

I've got the following JS running in FCM

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");

admin.initializeApp();

exports.sendSilentPushNotification = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
  const fcmToken = "epYalsbfm0VBnt_XF41Y8d:APA91bHu_Tn9gm05yn1Ho5q00bmaXc4RybJcsZuYZUawr7amc2AGNbrbid4CHoYJAsgH1mQ0-f4RHSQybSB8XcWbTI-d7v7XpU9U2dbfnVKVjnES2Ii834SevAq5fODCN1SUod1c_836";

  const payload = {
    "data": {
      "story_id": "story_12345",
    },
  };

  const options = {
    "aps": {
      "content-available": 1,
    },
  };

  try {
    const response = await admin.messaging().sendToDevice(fcmToken, payload, options);
    console.log("Sent silent push notification:", response);
    res.status(200).send("Silent push notification sent successfully");
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error sending silent push notification:", error);
    res.status(500).send("Failed to send silent push notification");
  }
});
```

And it's telling me the message is sent successfully. However, i'd expect console to print ''received remote notification w/ user info" based on this

```
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
        print("Received remote notification with userInfo: \(userInfo)")

        if let aps = userInfo["aps"] as? [String: AnyObject] {
            print("APS key found in userInfo: \(aps)")
            if let contentAvailable = aps["content-available"] as? Int, contentAvailable == 1 {
                print("Content-available key has value 1, processing journal entry")
                processJournalEntry()
                completionHandler(.newData)
            } else {
                print("Content-available key not found or has a different value")
                completionHandler(.noData)
            }
        } else {
            print("APS key not found in userInfo")
            completionHandler(.noData)
        }
    }
```

And that's not happening

- I've tried changing the payload quite a few times, but if i include APS or APNS in the dictionary i get an error telling me only data or notification are accepted
- Tried adding FireBaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled Bool No to my info.plist

Neither seem to work

Comment: Push only works on a physical device so youll need to try that ifnyou havent. You also must request and allow push permissions for your app.